# Carbon: error to create date , change date affect all variables

Tags: php, date, laravel-5, php-carbon

Why change all variables.

how to avoid my variables do not change its value

In my controller

```
public function show()
{
    $inicio = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s',"2016-02-04 11:00:00");
    $fin = $inicio;
    $otro = $fin->addHours(1);
    return view('horas',array('inicio'=>$inicio,'otro'=>$otro,'fin'=>$fin));
}
```

My views:

```
<p><b>Inicio: </b> {{$inicio}}</p>
<p><b>Fin: </b> {{$fin}}</p>
<p><b>Otro: </b> {{$otro}}</p>
```

The result

[image]

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change to the following:

```
$fin = $inicio->copy();
$otro = $fin->copy()->addHours(1);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because Carbon objects are mutable.

Try to clone them.

```
public function show()
{
    $inicio = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s',"2016-02-04 11:00:00");
    $fin = clone $inicio;
    $otro = clone $inicio; // not sure why you need this
    $fin->addHours(1);
    return view('horas',array('inicio'=>$inicio,'otro'=>$otro,'fin'=>$fin));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you are making `$fin=$inicio;` `$fin` will always have a reference to `$inicio` which means that if `$inicio` changes `$fin` will simultaneously change, this is how objects work this is object oriented world.
Try this instead:

```
public function show()
{
    $inicio = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s',"2016-02-04 11:00:00");
    $fin = clone $inicio;
    $otro = clone $fin->addHours(1);
    return view('horas',array('inicio'=>$inicio,'otro'=>$otro,'fin'=>$fin));
}
```